# Como imprimir las opciones seleccionadas de una opción múltiple dentro de un formulario en forma de lista con PHP

Tags: php, html, formularios, post

Tengo un formulario hecho en HTML y este tiene varios campos incluido uno de respuesta múltiple, en el php he tratado de imprimir los datos recibidos y todos los demás campos si están menos el ultimo que quiero que sea en forma de lista.

estas son mis opciones:

```
<form  action="formulario.PHP" method="post">
  Seleccione uno o mas colores ( presione Cr para seleccionar varios)
  <select multiple name="colores[]" size="6" >
    <option value="Rojo">Rojo</option>
    <option value="Verde">Verde</option>
    <option value="Azul">Azul</option>
    <option value="Amarillo">Amarillo</option>
    <option value="Blanco">Blanco</option>
    <option value="Negro">Negro</option>
    <option value="Naranja">Naranja</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="submit"  value="Enviar">
```

En php intente este método pero me da todas las respuestas escritas del formulario no solo las del campo que quiero.

```php
if ( isset($_POST['colores']) ){
  print_r($_POST['colores']);
}
if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {
  $colores = $_POST;
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ($colores as $color) {
    echo "<li>" . htmlspecialchars($color) . "</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

espero puedan ayudarme :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la asignación de la variable array `$colores` te estas trayendo todo el `$_POST`

Cambialo por

```php
$colores = $_POST['colores'];
```

O mejor aún si no sabes si colores va a tener opciones seleccionadas o valores, le predeterminas un array vacío.

```php
$colores = $_POST['colores'] ?? [];
```

`A = B ?? C` significa si B existe y no está vacío `A = B` sino `A = C`